# terrain position changes with terrain height?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am fairly new unity user and created a terrain using a heightmap for my player character to walk around in. However, I noticed that my player, even though the transform position is at (0,0,0), is floating below the terrain. The terrain is also positioned at (0,0,0), but the pivot point is far below it. When I set the terrain height to 1, the terrain is levelled with all other objects, but it changes its position according to its height (see picture). Is there a way to change that? Even when I write a script to set the position at game start to (0,0,0)[image: y] it will float above everything else.

Comment: how is your heightmap looking like? it sounds like that terrain simply already has a base height > 0 .. at least at the position you are viewing

Comment: Ah, I see - maybe I imported it with a minimum height > 0? Is there a way to change that afterwards or do I have to reimport the file again?

Comment: Like I would say `0` most probably means sea level .. which your mountains probably do not begin at .. so I suspect the data you pulled this from is correct and so is the terrain ... you probably just rather would want to go through it and normalize it to be at minimum `0` .. or just manually move the pivot as you did